# Show that if $(κ_t)_{t≥0}$ is the transition semigroup of a strong solution to an SDE, $t↦(κ_tf)(x)$ is continuous for all $x$ and suitable $f:ℝ→ℝ$

Tags: probability-theory, markov-process, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space
- $b,\sigma:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be Lipschitz continuous and $$Lf:=bf'+\frac12\sigma^2f''\;\;\;\text{for }f\in C^2(\mathbb R)$$
- $W$ be a Brownian motion on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$

We know that for any $X_0:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ there is an unique (up to indistinguishability) process $X$ on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ with $$X_t=X_0+\int_0^tb(X_s)\:{\rm d}s+\int_0^t\sigma(X_s)\:{\rm d}W_s\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge0\text{ almost surely}\tag1.$$ Moreover, there is a continuous process $(X^x_t)_{(t,\:x)\in[0,\:\infty)\times\mathbb R}$ on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ with $$X_t^x=x+\int_0^tb(X_s)\:{\rm d}s+\int_0^t\sigma(X_s)\:{\rm d}W_s\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge0\text{ almost surely for all }x\in\mathbb R\tag2.$$

Now, let $$\kappa_t(x,B):=\operatorname P\left[X_t^x\in B\right]\;\;\;\text{for all }(x,B)\in\mathbb R\times\mathcal B(\mathbb R)\text{ and }t\ge0.$$ Note that $$[0,\infty)\times\mathbb R\ni(t,x)\mapsto\kappa_t(x,B)\tag3$$ is Borel measurable for all $B\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$. In particular, $\kappa_t$ is a Markov kernel on $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$ for all $t\ge0$. Let $\mathcal F^X$ denot the filtration generated by $X$. It can be shown that $$\operatorname E\left[f(X_{s+t})\mid\mathcal F^X_s\right]=\left.\operatorname E\left[f(X^x_t)\right]\right|_{x\:=\:X_s}\;\;\;\text{almost surely}\tag4$$ for all bounded Borel measurable $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ and $s,t\ge0$. So, $X$ is a time-homogeneous Markov process with transition semigroup $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$.

> Let $$\kappa_tf:=\int\kappa_t(\;\cdot\;,{\rm d}y)f(y)$$ for bounded Borel measurable $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$. Suppose we want that $$[0,\infty)\ni t\mapsto(\kappa_tf)(x)\tag5$$ is continuous for all $x\in\mathbb R$ and $f$ belonging to a suitable class $\mathcal C$ of bounded Borel measurable $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$. By time-homogeneity, it should suffice to consider the continuity at $t=0$.

Usually, this is shown for $\mathcal C=C_0(\mathbb R)$ in the following way: By the Itō formula, $$(\kappa_tf)(x)=\operatorname E\left[f(X^x_t)\right]=f(x)+\operatorname E\left[\int_0^t(Lf)(X_s)\:{\rm d}s\right]\;\;\;\text{for all }(t,x)\in[0,\infty)\times\mathbb R\tag6$$ and hence $$\left\|\kappa_tf-f\right\|_\infty\le\left(\sup_K|bf'|+\frac12\sup_K\sigma^2|f''|\right)t\xrightarrow{t\to0+}0\tag7$$ with $K:=\operatorname{supp}f$ for all $f\in C_c^2(\mathbb R)$. Now, $C_c^2(\mathbb R)$ is dense in $C_0(\mathbb R)$ and hence we obtain $\left\|\kappa_tf-f\right\|_\infty\xrightarrow{t\to0+}0$ for all $f\in C_0(\mathbb R)$. We have shown that $(5)$ is even uniformly continuous at $t=0$ for all $f\in C_0(\mathbb R)$.

> On the other hand, there is the general claim (cf. [my other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3081858/if-%ce%ba-t-t%e2%89%a50-is-the-transition-semigroup-of-a-continuous-markov-process-is)) that if $X$ is a general right-continuous time-homogeneous Markov process with transition semigroup $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$, $(1)$ is continuous for all $x\in\mathbb R$ and bounded continuous $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$.
>
> So, the question is: What's the point of proving the continuity for our special $X$ only for $\mathcal C=C_0(\mathbb R)$? Is it to obtain the uniform continuity which cannot be shown for all bounded continuous $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$? And how can we prove that $(1)$ is continuous for all bounded continuous $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are after. There are plenty of techniques to prove that $x \mapsto Ef(X_t^x)$ is continuous for all $f \in C_b$. One possibility is to use moment esimates (see e.g. Corollary 19.27 in the book by Schilling, 2nd ed.) or the fact that $x \mapsto X_t^x$ is actually continuous (see 19.28 in Schillings book) or argue via the infinitesimal generator (as you suggested here)... Note that it doesn't matter whether you prove the continuity for $f \in C_b$ or only for $f \in C_0$; a standard truncation argument shows that both are equivalent.

Comment: @saz What is the "standard truncation argument"? And in which sense are they equivalent?

Comment: $\kappa_t f$ is continuous for all $f \in C_b$ if and only if $\kappa_t f$ is continuous for all $f \in C_0$. One implication is obvious; for the other one fix $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and choose $R>0$ suffuciently large such that $$\mathbb{P}(|X_t^y| \geq R) \leq \epsilon$$ for all $y \in B(x,1)$ (use Markov inequality+moment bounds). Pick some truncation function $\chi$ such that $\chi(y)=1$ for $|y| \leq R$ and $\chi(y)=0$ for $|y| \geq R+1$. Clearly, $\tilde{f} := \chi \cdot f \in C_0$ and so $\kappa_t \tilde{f}$ is continuous.

Comment: Using $$|\kappa_t f(x)-\kappa_tf(y)| \leq |\kappa_t \tilde{f}(x)-\kappa_t \tilde{f}(y)| + 2 \|f\|_{\infty} \sup_{z \in B(x,1)} \mathbb{P}(|X_t^z| \geq R)$$ for any $y \in B(x,1)$ it follows that $\kappa_t f$ is continuous.

Comment: @saz Thank you for your comment. However, I'm a bit confused why you're talking about the continuity of $x\mapsto\operatorname E\left[f(X^x_t)\right]$, since the question is about the continuity of $t\mapsto(\kappa_tf)(x)=\operatorname E\left[f(X^x_t)\right]$

Comment: Sorry about that; I mixed things up. However, the idea doesn't change much. For fixed $t$, $x$ choose $R>0$ such that $$\mathbb{P}(|X_s^x| \geq R) \leq \epsilon \quad \text{for all $s \leq t+1$}.$$ Pick $\chi$ with the properties from my previous comment(s) and define $\tilde{f}:=f \chi$. Then we have $$|\kappa_t f(x)-\kappa_s f(x)| \leq |\kappa_t (f-\tilde{f})(x)| + |\kappa_t \tilde{f}(x)-\kappa_s \tilde{f}(x)| + |\kappa_s (f-\tilde{f})(x)|$$ As $$|\kappa_t(f-\tilde{f})(x)| \leq 2 \|f\|_{\infty} \mathbb{P}(|X_t^x| \geq R)$$ this gives

Comment: $$|\kappa_t f(x)-\kappa_s f(x)|  \leq 4 \|f\|_{\infty} \sup_{u \leq t+1} \mathbb{P}(|X_u^x| \geq R) + |\kappa_t \tilde{f}-\kappa_s \tilde{f}(x)|$$ for any $u \leq t+1$. For the first term now use the choice of $R$ and for the second one the conntinuity of $t \mapsto \kappa_{t} \tilde{f}(x)$

Comment: @saz It's clear to me now how we obtain $(\kappa_tf)(x)\to f(x)\xrightarrow{t\to0+}$ for fixed $x$ and $f\in C_b(\mathbb R)$, but are even able to show that this convergence is uniformly with respect to $x$? I've asked a separate question for this:https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3098782/47771